# D9 Can't change field regions or enable fields in node displays UI (e.g. full, teaser, etc.). Can I enable fields programmatically?

Tags: php, field, region, drupal-9

I was handed this D9 website and I just trying to enable some fields in node displays (e.g. full, teaser, etc.) and to assign them to regions, but I can't do it. The loading gif goes on forever and when I click submit it goes back to disabled or the original there are a lot of fields on these node displays. This might be a cache problem. I can't figure it out on the backend.

Is there any way I can enable these fields programmatically or in the database?

How do I assign a region to the field in the code below?

```
/** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityDisplayRepositoryInterface $display_repository **/
$display_repository = \Drupal::service('entity_display.repository');

// Assign widget settings for the default form mode.
$display_repository->getFormDisplay('node', 'node_type')
   ->setComponent('field_name', [
        'region' => 'content',
   ])
   ->save();

// Assign display settings for the 'default' and 'full' view modes.
$display_repository->getViewDisplay('node', 'node_type')
   ->setComponent('field_name', [
        'label' => 'hidden',
        'region' => 'content',
   ])
   ->save();


$display_repository->getViewDisplay('node', 'node_type', 'full')
   ->setComponent('field_name', [
        'label' => 'hidden',
        'type' => 'string_textfield',
   ])
   ->save();
```

If the above is the correct code, what function hook can I use to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

module/module.routing.yml

```
module.fields:
  path: '/module/fields'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\module\Controller\ModuleController::fields'
    _title: 'Enable fields in node after changing field type'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

module/src/Controller/ModuleController.php

```
namespace Drupal\module\Controller;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
/**
 * Class ModuleController.
 ** @package Drupal\lotus\Controller
 */ class ModuleController extends ControllerBase
 {
    /**
      * Fields.
      * * @return string
      * Return Fields string.
      */
    public function fields()
    {

   $display_repository = \Drupal::service('entity_display.repository');

   // Assign widget settings for the default form mode.
   $display_repository->getFormDisplay('node', 'bundle')
   ->setComponent('field_name', [
        'region' => 'content',
   ])
   ->save();

   // Assign display settings for the 'default' and 'full' view modes.
   $display_repository->getViewDisplay('node', 'bundle')
   ->setComponent('field_name', [
        'region' => 'content',
   ])
   ->save();


   $display_repository->getViewDisplay('node', 'bundle', 'full')
   ->setComponent('field_name', [
        'region' => 'content',
   ])
   ->save();

       return ['#type' => 'markup',
       '#markup' => $this->t('Field field_name has been enabled!!'),];


    }
 }
```